# Remove Vertical Space in Bootstrap 4 Row

Tags: html, css, laravel, layout, bootstrap-4

I want to remove the vertical space (look at this image below => red mark)

Using : Bootstrap 4

Preview : https://jsfiddle.net/3vcp8o15/

[image]

i've tried to put class m-0 and p-0 inside each col-6, but its still doesn't work.

is any wrong with my code?

here my current code:

```html
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 w-100">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row px-2">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <h5>Detail Transaksi</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row mt-4 px-2" style="font-size: 12px;">
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Kode Transaksi</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Tanggal</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Kasir</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row px-2" style="font-size: 14px;">
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3 px-4" style="font-size: 14px;">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="drml-bg-lightgray">
                                            <th class="text-left">Nama Produk</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" width="100">Jumlah</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="text-secondary">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-left">Lorem Ipsum</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">Lorem Ipsum</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row px-2">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <h5>Detail Transaksi</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row mt-4 px-2" style="font-size: 12px;">
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Kode Transaksi</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Tanggal</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Kasir</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row px-2" style="font-size: 14px;">
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3 px-4" style="font-size: 14px;">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="drml-bg-lightgray">
                                            <th class="text-left">Nama Produk</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" width="100">Jumlah</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="text-secondary">
                                        @foreach($transaction->retail_transaction_products as $row)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="text-left">{{ $row->product->name }}</td>
                                                <td class="text-center">{{ $row->quantity }}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row px-2">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <h5>Detail Transaksi</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row mt-4 px-2" style="font-size: 12px;">
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Kode Transaksi</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Tanggal</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Kasir</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row px-2" style="font-size: 14px;">
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">{{ $transaction->code }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">{{ formatted_date($transaction->created_at) }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">{{ $transaction->branch_operational->open_employee->name }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3 px-4" style="font-size: 14px;">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="drml-bg-lightgray">
                                            <th class="text-left">Nama Produk</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" width="100">Jumlah</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="text-secondary">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-left">Lorem Ipsum</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">Lorem Ipsum</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row px-2">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <h5>Detail Transaksi</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row mt-4 px-2" style="font-size: 12px;">
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Kode Transaksi</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Tanggal</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p>Kasir</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row px-2" style="font-size: 14px;">
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">{{ $transaction->code }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">{{ formatted_date($transaction->created_at) }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">{{ $transaction->branch_operational->open_employee->name }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3 px-4" style="font-size: 14px;">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="drml-bg-lightgray">
                                            <th class="text-left">Nama Produk</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" width="100">Jumlah</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="text-secondary">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-left">Lorem Ipsum</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">Lorem Ipsum</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is anyone can help me? thanks in advance!

i've tried to use float-right/left too, but i think its not dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to CSS:

```
   .card {
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Or for bootstrap make it this:

```
<div class="card h-100">
```

working here: https://jsfiddle.net/e5zxqnfp/

Comment: but its not remove the space, but only hide the space by increasing the height of the card, do you have an idea to remove that space?

Comment: @MuhammadRobbiZulfikar You are using a grid. The purpose of a grid is to do that. I would recommend using 2 grids then, one for the left side and one for right side. Then it will go away.

Comment: sir, how to use 2 girds ?

Comment: ah im done now!! thanks, im using 2 grids by using 

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: @MuhammadRobbiZulfikar Great, glad to have helped.  I am curious, can you post a fiddle of what you did?